# Assign 1 array from a list to a var and assign rest of the arrays in the list to another var

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a list of n ndarrays and I want to loop through the list to split them into 2 variables such that the ith array is assigned to "a" and rest of them to "b" such that b doesnt contains i. (Say when i=0, it goes to a and rest go to be, now i=1, it goes to a but rest including i=0 and excluding i=1 go to b)

```
#n=3
lis=[x,y,z] #where x,y,z are ndarrays
for i in lis:
a=i
b=lis.remove(i)
```

which gives me a value error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

So I tried the below:

```
b=[ j for j in lis if not (j==i).all()]
```

But this returns an empty list.

I used the itertools.permutations but it gave an output of 4 arrays instead of all the permutations.

At this point, I am out of ideas. I am asking for a direction so that I can get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `a, b = lis.pop(i), lis`

Comment: No it doesnt works with ndarrays.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding. but if `lis = [x, y, z]`, and `lis` is of type `list` and `x, y, and z` are `numpy.ndarray`, then if you want to store the array at `i`-th element into  `a` and rest of the arrays as a `list` into `b` the above code works.

Comment: You get the error in `remove(i)`, since that selects the item by value, and equality tests on arrays produce arrays.  If you `for i in range(len(lis):...`, you can `pop` by index.  Just be careful about making necessary list copies.  `pop` modifies the list itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

You already have y, you can get the others by just deleting y from lis.

Maybe you could try this:

`for i in range(len(lis)):
    if np.array_equal(lis[i],y):
        del lis[i]
        break`